Vite 'The following dependencies are imported but could not be resolved'
I'm trying to migrate from Symfony encore (that uses webpack under the hood) to vite and stuck with this issue
Error: The following dependencies are imported but could not be resolved:
vue (imported by /root/Gyant/vocwebmanager/web/vwm/js/app.js)
Here is my vite.config.js
import {defineConfig} from 'vite';
import path from 'path';
import symfonyPlugin from 'vite-plugin-symfony';
import vue from '@vitejs/plugin-vue';

export default defineConfig({
  plugins: [
    vue({
      template: {
        transformAssetUrls: {
          includeAbsolute: false,
          base: null,
        },
      },
    }),
    symfonyPlugin({
      viteDevServerHostname: 'localhost'
    }),
  ],
  optimizeDeps: {
    force: true,
  },
  preview: {
    port: 8080,
    strictPort: true,
  },
  server: {
    port: 8080,
    strictPort: true,
    host: '0.0.0.0',
    origin: '',
    hmr: {
      host: 'localhost'
    }
  },
  root: '/assets',
  base: '/assets',
  publicDir: false,
  resolve: {
    extensions: ['.js', '.json', '.vue', '.ts'],
    alias: {
      root: path.resolve(__dirname, './'),
    },
  },
  build: {
    emptyOutDir: false,
    sourcemap: process.env.MODE !== 'production',
    manifest: true,
    cssCodeSplit: true,
    outDir: './web/assets/',
    rollupOptions: {
      input: {
        app: path.resolve(__dirname, './web/vwm/js/app.js'),
      },
    },
  }
});

app.js
import {createApp} from 'vue';


const vm = createApp();

I tried to find any answer on the internet with no success

It's unclear what project structure looks like, because vwm/js/app.js  is not contained in root dir. This could be a problem. Disable symfony plugin to isolate its effect

@EstusFlask I tried to disable it. No effect unfortunately. The app.js file is not in root dir and it should not be there. Vite recognises the app.js file, but for some reason it cannot start dev server on the line with the import statement. import {createApp} from 'vue';

A common setup is src/ in project root.  I mean app.js is outside the hierarchy of root dir. This can affect how node modules are resolved, which "vue" is. I didn't try how vite will work under this condition but I wouldn't be surprised if it fails because of this. I'd suggest to start with a generic vite config (nothing but vue() in plugins) and then iteratively customize it

Yeah, but isn’t src/ is outside the hierarchy of root dir?

Vite's root dir is where package.json and node_modules are. Node modules are expected to resolve relatively to it. This is what a workable dir structure looks like https://codesandbox.io/p/devbox/vue-3-vite-template-zunoq

@EstusFlask path to app.js file is web/vwm/js/app.js. I don’t really understand why vite can’t resolve vue properly. For me, it seems like everything as it should be

And what is the path to vite config and package.json? As noted, it's unclear what project structure looks like, while it could be the root cause of the problem

@EstusFlask They’re both in root dir.

Ans what are their absolute paths? Root dir is ambiguous term. Please, check https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask . The question needs to contain all necessary info to reproduce the problem. Currently it isn't and this requires follow-up questions to understand your problem

Issue is resolved by changing root: '/assets in vite.config.js to root: ./
